# jQuery linkbutton error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, linkbutton

This jquery function working fine for button submit but not working for link button. Why?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%= txtUserName.UniqueID %>: {minlength: 5, required: true},
                    <%= txtPassword.UniqueID %>: {minlength: 5, required: true},
                    <%= txtEmail.UniqueID %>: {required: true},
                    <%= txtURL.UniqueID %>: {required: true},
                    <%=  chkbox.UniqueID%>: {required:true},
                    <%= textcredit.UniqueID %>:{required:true},
                 }, 
                messages: {
                    <%= txtUserName.UniqueID %>: {
                        required: "Plaese enter your name",
                        minlength: "User name must be atleaet of 5 characters"
                    },
                    <%= txtPassword.UniqueID %>: { 
                        required: "Plaese enter your password", 
                        minlength: "Password must be atleaet of 5 characters"
                    },
                    <%= txtEmail.UniqueID %>:{ required: "Plaese enter your Email Id",},
                    <%= txtURL.UniqueID %>:{ required: "Plaese enter Website URL",},
                    <%= chkbox.UniqueID %>:{ required: "Plaese select this chek box",} , 
                    <%= chkbox.UniqueID %>:{    
                        required: "Plaese select creditcard", 
                        minlength: "User name must be atleaet of 5 characters"
                    },
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table width="50%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" style="border: solid 1px navy; background-color: #d5d5d5;">
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: It might be more helpful if you provide some more of your code. What exactly, for instance, is the server code outputting? Those values may be meaningless to jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649762/asp-net-linkbutton-imagebutton-and-jquery-validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submit button posts back to the server naturally; the linkbutton posts back to the server using a `__doPostBack` trick that Microsoft developed.  That's why @Yuriy's solution is a good one.  Alternatively, you could just have a common method:

```
function validateForm(id) {
  return $("#" + id).valid();
}
```

And have all your buttons call your function.  There are a couple of other JQuery/HTML 5 specific ways to handle this.

Answer (score 5):

Add at the page's bottom this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var originalDoPostBack = __doPostBack;
     __doPostBack = function (sender, args) {
          if ($("#form1").valid() === true) {
               originalDoPostBack(sender, args);
          }
     }
</script>
```

Or add `OnClientClick` property to LinkButton: `OnClientClick="if(!$('#form1').valid()) return false;"`